# Deny PHP uploads in any subdirectory under file path wp-content/uploads/

Tags: php, upload, exploit

I run a very small hosting company (100 accounts) and we're having problems with hackers putting php files in the uploads/ folder and executing background scripts which cause mass spamming. This destroys our ip reputation and users can't send email through our server.

Is it possible to deny all .php uploads and execution under any filepath containing /wp-content/uploads via the server so it's a default config on all accounts? Maybe through a default php.ini file?

I know it's possible through the .htaccess file, but I need a solution that can be a default config for all cpanel accounts as soon as wordpress is set up.

Comment: `php_flag engine off` through httpd-vhosts.conf (or httpd.conf) using `<DirectoryMatch ...>` rather than .htaccess?

Comment: Why don't you fix your applications such that all that hacking attempts fail instead of fiddling around with the consequences?

Comment: Nico, the application that's being hacked is wordpress. Some users install wordpress and abandon it so it's never updated.

Comment: CD001 - yes! I think adding this to httpd.conf this is the answer
`<DirectoryMatch "^.*/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/.*">
 php_flag engine off
 AddType text/plain .php
</DirectoryMatch>`